# Para que serve GUID em projetos do Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um projeto "base" em C# MVC (login, controle de acessoe afins), para replicar em outros projetos, que consiste em copiar os fontes e algumas vezes renomear o projeto.

Tenho que alterar o GUID do assembly? Para que serve ele? Tem algum problema de ter 2 projetos com o mesmo GUID?

Comment: Talvez seja interessante criar um template de projeto ao invés de ficar copiando e renomeando. Diminui o esforço e as chances de erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você **copiar** o projeto para outra solution, não tem problema. O Visual Studio usa esses GUIDs para gerenciar as referências/dependências entre os projetos. Esse é um exemplo do GUID:

```
<ProjectGuid>{0186C50F-7FBA-43D1-B403-D8BE75193671}</ProjectGuid>
```

Se você tentar **adicionar** (ao invés de copiar) um projeto com uma GUID repetida em uma solution, o Visual Studio irá automaticamente gerar um novo GUID para esse projeto.

O mesmo ocorre se você tenta fazer um **unload** do projeto (pelo Visual Studio), editar o `.csproj` e tentar alterar o GUID do projeto, colocando um repetido (na solution). Ao fazer o reload, o Visual Studio irá pegar o GUID que a solution (.sln) tem para o projeto, e irá sobrescrever.

Se você tentar editar o próprio `.sln` tentando forçar múltiplos projetos a ter o mesmo GUID, ao abrir o Visual Studio, ele irá automaticamente gerar novos GUIDs para os duplicados.

Isso pode ser um problema se você usar o mesmo projeto em diferentes solutions, pois se por algum dos motivos acima o Visual Studio gerar um novo GUID para um projeto, ao abrí-lo em outra solution pode dar problemas de referência/dependência.

Uma forma de resolver isso (caso você precise ter o mesmo projeto em diferentes solutions) é fazer com que ambas solutions utilizem o mesmo GUID para o projeto compartilhado, assim elas não vão ficar sobrepondo o GUID da outra no arquivo `.csproj`. Mas isso é questão de preferência, entendo que cada forma tem prós e contras, é necessário analisar como você ou sua equipe prefere trabalhar.

Isso é explicado [aqui (está em inglês, no entanto)](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20151205-BeCarefulWhenCopyingVisualStudioProjects.html).

Alguns projetos contém também o GUID abaixo:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Como é o caso da **WebApplication**, que simplesmente faz com que o Visual Studio abra opções de menu diferentes para o projeto.

---

Eu particularmente já tentei utilizar projetos compartilhados em diferentes solutions, mas acabei optando por algo diferente. Quando eu tenho um projeto que gostaria de ter o fonte compartilhado com outras solutions, eu crio um pacote do Nuget e o publico em um *package source* interno, e o instalo nos projetos onde preciso utilizá-lo.

Comment: pessoal ainda nao entendi pra que serve guid?